# Comparison of fastq files reads

Tags: python, linux, comparison, bioinformatics, fastq

My goal is to compare reads from two different fastq files. For reference, this is what the fastq file contains:

> @SRR1174213.1 HWI-1116:69:D0JBGACXX:2:1101:1388:2317 length=100
> GGGACAATAAGGTCACGGTGTGCATCTGTGTTCCAAGGCTTTGAAGTGATGAAAACTTCATCTCTACTCTTTATAAGGCCTTTGTCTATGGCTTTGGCCA
> +SRR1174213.1 HWI-1116:69:D0JBGACXX:2:1101:1388:2317 length=100
> 8;?DDDDDFFF>2AFFFFBFGEE@AHHIFFG@FFFECECFEIIIB<09???DDFF3=@<CFECFGFGE@EECEFCAEECE;?);?;6.;@C25>;3>A

The breakdown of the fastq:

*This line contains reads ID

> @SRR1174213.1 HWI-1116:69:D0JBGACXX:2:1101:1388:2317 length=100

*The line contains sequence

> GGGACAATAAGGTCACGGTGTGCATCTGTGTTCCAAGGCTTTGAAGTGATGAAAACTTCATCTCTACTCTTTATAAGGCCTTTGTCTATGGCTTTGGCCA
> *Again, read ID
> +SRR1174213.1 HWI-1116:69:D0JBGACXX:2:1101:1388:2317 length=100

*This line contains the quality scores for each base in the sequence

> 8;?DDDDDFFF>2AFFFFBFGEE@AHHIFFG@FFFECECFEIIIB<09??DDFF3=@<CFECFGFGE@EECEFCAEECE;?);?;6.;@C25>;3>A

The following are the comparisons to perform:

1. How many common reads are between the two fastq files?
2. How many reads are present in one fastq file that are not present in the other? i.e reads that are unique to each file.
3. Where and how do the sequences differ in both files? Is there a difference in nucleotide base at the end of the sequence(3' end), the start of the sequence(5'end) or is it somewhere in the middle of the sequence? Is there a difference in length of the sequence? If so, what is the length and what is the difference? I would like to get the original sequences plus the difference between them for analysis.
4. Does the quality score differ? Where and how do the quality of sequences differs?

Answer (score 1):

no python, you want `comm` https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm

> How many common reads are between the two fastq files?

```
comm -12 <(gunzip -c in1.fq.gz |paste - - - - | cut -f 2 | sort | uniq ) <(gunzip -c in2.fq.gz |paste - - - - | cut -f 2 | sort | uniq)
```